# Colored vertices on a directed graph with sets of Euler cycles

Tags: color, graphs

Is there a way to make the vertices on the following directed graph with a set Euler cycles  colored? Provide the TeX code as well as explain how to color vertices![image]

Comment: *You* should provide the TeX code you have. We don't like “do it for me” questions. It would be better if you provided us the code and asked more precise questions.

Comment: If I had the TeX code, I would have provided it; I cannot find anything close to the graph I have provided. Can you imagine how a directed graph with sets of Euler cycles might be in TeX?

Comment: You can try using TikZ. http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/

Comment: @Eric Well, as susis strolch said. Try with TikZ. You just need to know how to put nodes with letters, how to draw circles, and how to draw arrows. And that is pretty simple in TikZ.

Comment: I went to Susis Stroich link; no directed graphs with sets of Euler cycles are in the repository of graphs. If anyone can reproduce the graph in TeX code, then I can figure out how to color the vertices.

Comment: @Eric As Manuel already told you we are willing to help but not to do your work for your. And colouring some vertices is a piece of cake with TikZ.

Comment: If you can show me how to draw a graph with two vertices, one edge, I can figure out the rest. Do you have code for such a graph?

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of drawing 2 nodes with a line connecting them? The `tikz` manual explains this fully - did you look at the documentation?

Comment: @Eric Let me google that for you. How about this: http://http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160643/

Comment: @susisstrolch There's something funny about that link or my browser. (But I've not had the issue before.) It looks for an entirely other web site and fails to find it.

Comment: I thought I would consult experts to save time but none of the TeX experts on this thread appear to have a thread of expertise!

Comment: @cfr Thanks. There was a http too much. Here is the correct link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160643/

Comment: @Eric [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To expand on the comments, on this site,
a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I
get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application
(e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this
complicated thing for me" tend to get closed. It will always help to make your question clear and simple by giving a
[minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228);
you'll stand a greater chance of getting quick and specific help.